# NetSuite Look-up Record ID Using any Field On a Record in SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

We use custom segments to track sales channel on sales orders.  The Sales Channel custom segment record has three fields: `Internal ID, Name, Raw_Channel`.  Example values are:

```
1, Amazon.com, AMAZON_COM
2, Amazon.ca, AMAZON_CA
3, Amazon.uk, AMAZON_UK
```

`Raw_Channel` is a text field on Sales Orders that is populated when an order is imported to NetSuite by our marketplace connector (the connector pulls orders from the various Amazon marketplaces and imports them into NetSuite).

What I'm hoping to do is to use the `Raw_Channel` field to look up the Sales Channel ID and set the value of the Sales Channel drop-down custom segment field using an After Record Submit script.  Below is a start but it obviously won't work since `nlapiLookUpField` uses `Internal ID` to look-up values but I only have `Raw_Channel` as a reference which is not the ID.

My ultimate question is, how do I get the Sales Channel Internal ID by using a non-ID field as a look-up field?  Help is very much appreciated!

```
function setChannel (){
    var rawchannel = nlapiGetFieldValue('custbody_raw_channel')
    var channelid = nlapiLookUpField('cseg_tt_channel', rawchannel, 'id')
    nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_cseg_tt_channel', channelid)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nlapiLookUpField` is only useful if you already have the Internal Id of the record.

You will need to construct a search using `nlapiSearchRecord` or `nlapiCreateSearch` with a filter for the raw channel.

You can read more about scripting searches in the Help Center [here](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=part_N3000196.html).

I find [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netsuite-search-export/gglbgdfbkaelbjpjkiepdmfaihdokglp) immensely helpful when building searches in SuiteScript. It allows you to create a search in the UI and automatically generate the SuiteScript code.

Comment: Got it.  I'll take a look at your suggested references and see what I can come up with.  Thanks